# Comma links in LTR texts in RTL arabic document

Tags: xetex, arabic, bidi

I insert an english fragment into arabic text. If there is a comma after a digit, I get surprising result. The comma goes before the number, not after.

[image]

The font above is "Amiri". I tested also "arabtype.ttf" from Microsoft (http://www.microsoft.com/typography/OpenTypeDev/arabic/intro.htm) and got the same result. Therefore I consider it is not a bug, but some important feature.

Question 1, not important, just for curiosity: where can I read about this feature?

A general solution is to somehow remove `script=arabic` from font for LTR texts. I suspect it is a hard task.

An easy solution for this concrete problem is to add `\hbox{}` after the number. Then:

The question 2: are there other surprises for english text fragments when using `script=arabic`?

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}

\begin{document}

\font\f="Amiri:script=arabic"
\f

\LRE{Print 42, then exit, but not.}

\LRE{Print 42: then exit: but not.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Further special cases: 1) I should also add `\hbox{}` before the number 2) Parenthesis are mirrored 3) I stopped here and gave up. Now I do change fonts. Still, I'm happy to hear the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `fontspec` to select fonts and font features. You can change the script now using `\addfontfeature{Script=Latin}`.

To make things more convenient it is possible to *renew* `\LRE`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}

\let\oldLRE\LRE
\renewcommand*{\LRE}[1]{\oldLRE{\addfontfeature{Script=Latin} #1}} % <-- Change script to latin within \LRE 

\begin{document}

   \LRE{Print 42, then exit, but not.}

   \LRE{Print 42: then exit: but not.}

\end{document}
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Comment: This is what exactly I wanted to avoid. In general case I don't know which fonts are in use. Therefore a good solution should somehow switch "script=Arabic" on and off.

Comment: In that case use `\addfontfeature{Script=Latin}`. I've updated my answer accordingly.